# Securely Transfer Password from C# to Java Application

Tags: c#, java, windows

I have a C# app which calls anumber of java applications some of which use SSH for various things. At the moment i get many pop up boxes from the java command line apps asking for passwords. I wonder if you have any concrete suggestions for how i could enter the password in C# then securely pass it to the java apps. At the moment i call the java apps using shell exec with many command line parameters.

The only thing i can think of is to somehow encrypt the password in c# and then decrypt it in java. but i suspect that they dont share a common decrypt process or if they did i'd have to pass the keys between the programs also ...

any suggestions?

David

Comment: Are you asking for a common way on how to pass passwords etc. on via parameters/calls...or are you specifically asking how to do this with the applications at hand? If the last applies, we'd need to know what applications those are.

Comment: specifically with c# and java but i guess the question is more general

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that encryption is a good solution.

But I can suggest you something else. You can write passwod in clear text to the stdin of java application from C# application. Java application should read the password from STDIN and use it. It is secure enough because unless reverse engineering or connecting to JVM using remote debugging API I do not know ways to intercept this stream. If both C# and java apps run on the same machine you cannot sniff the stream too.

Comment: This is actually safer than encrypting it. Extracting the encryption key from either C# or Java should be pretty easy, even with obfuscation.

Comment: isnt this just as secure as passing the password as a commandline argument?

Comment: I would like to know which methods of encryption both C# and java support and whether they would have to share the same encryption key?

Comment: @GreyCloud - no, this is more secure.  the command line arguments may be visible to other users on a shared system, but the stdin will not be.